# Why would my production site and my dev site have different migrations?

Tags: django, git

I have a django site where I work on my dev, git push it to an online repo at bitbucket, and then I pull it onto my production server using

```
git pull --no-edit origin master
```

When I check the repo, the migration files mirror what is on my local machine exactly, but when I ssh into my server and look at the same migration files, they are different...

Why wouldn't these files be the same and how can I make sure they are the same, it is causing problems when I try to dump my data from my local database and put it into the main one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening to you is probably that in some moment your local files didn't override with the files of the server. The best thing you can do is to put everything exactly as it exist in the server. To do that:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Apart from that I wouldn't recommend to upload the migration files to the server. In django they are like build files. Take into account if you make a change in your model in development, then you'll have to do the migrations and you'll get a new file like 0002_auto_*****. Imagine that you don't want this change in production, you'll have to do a new migration in development, and you'll get a another migration file 0003_auto_*****. You don't want that in your production environment, right?

To ignore folder migration you just have to add it to `.gitignore`.

Comment: That's why you use a development branch in git, and you merge into your production branch when it's ready. It is **highly recommended** that you create your migrations on your development machine, test them, and then push them to production. Migrations are not fail-safe, even though Django puts in a high amount of effort to make them that way. Migrations can and will occasionally produce errors that aren't easy to recover from, especially when your database doesn't support atomic schema alterations. You don't want that to happen on production, so you should **always** test them locally.

Comment: To quote [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#the-commands): "The migration files for each app live in a “migrations” directory inside of that app, and are designed to be committed to, and distributed as part of, its codebase. You should be making them once on your development machine and then running the same migrations on your colleagues’ machines, your staging machines, and eventually your production machines."

Comment: ok I guess I don't need them on the production server, I never thought about it like that. How would I add every migration folder to gitignore? Do I have to add the absolute filepaths to every gitignore or is there a way to catch all the ignore folders?

Comment: @knbk I don't agree with you. I don't think I deserved a down vote because the answer is not incorrect. I just expressed my **personal recommendation** about how I use migrations. And I stand to what I said. I do not recommend to upload the migrations, even thought the official site say so. They say _You should think of migrations as a version control system for your database schema_, but I don't need a version control system in django, because I have git, which is a real version control. Django is not.

Comment: Following with the comment above... And just ask yourself how many times you used your migrations as a version control, I bet never. I've never use them that way, because I use git for that purpose. Furthermore, think about the value that uploading the migrations to your server adds to your project. It has no value, do you really want to have a track of all your model changes??? If I've changed my models 1000 times I would get 1000 files.

Comment: Just to finish, @deltaskelta you can do what you want. You can follow django site convention or not. But I really think you don't have to follow them just because they tell you, but because you agree with them

Comment: When one of two options is a potential for disastrous **data loss** on your production server, I no longer care whether you agree or not. You are wrong. I'm not saying you have to push 1000 files to production, you can recreate your migrations whenever you like, but **test them before you apply them in production**.

Comment: For reference: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24435, https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24037 and https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23474. Migrations should be considered code, and should be tested, especially since it is auto-generated and acts on live data.

Comment: @knbk Again, I don't agree with you. there is no potential of data loss related with migrations. How? You can loss data if you mess up the database, not changing the migrations. It's good at least you agree that it make no sense to push 1000 files and of course you have to test changes before upload them to production (nobody does that). What I was saying, and why you downvoted me unfairly, is that even though django developers uses migration as a version control, my **personal opinion** is that it's useless, because django is not a version control system, git is

Comment: @knbk don't get mad buddy, it's just that I don't agree with you, nor with the version control system django developers created ;-)

Comment: Im not mad :) Your recommendation to add them to `.gitignore` strongly suggests that these files should be local to your deployment. If you only suggest to use a separate (tested) set of migrations for your production branch, that's an entirely valid opinion, but that's not how I read your post. To me it now suggests what I consider a bad, dangerous practice, one I often have to help people recover from.

Answer (score 0):

Migration files can be different on different machines. For example on local you create a model then makemigrations then migrate. Then you decide to push and pull on production. Then on local you make changes, makemigrate, and migrate changes, Then you make more changes to models locally and repeat makemigrations and migrate, then you make this again say 4 times, and then you decide to push to repo and pull from repo on production, so now you need to makemigrations on production and probably will have only one migration for all of 4 changes.

One thing you should remember is that if you already have necessary tables, but you have migrations that do not need to executed, you can migrate them like:

```
./manage.py migrate appname 0001 --fake
```

so this migration will be applied without really changing structure (because it already fits your needs)

Comment: Downvoted for the same reason: it is **highly recommended** to have your migrations in source control. If you need incremental development, you can do that in a separate branch. You can create new migrations when you merge the changes into your production branch, but **always** create and test your migrations before you push them to production.